# How to structure your NodeJS application in different modules?

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

so far i've learned a bit about NodeJS. But now i want to write a huge enterprise app with it and i'm wondering how to setup the structure correctly? Coming from other languages like PHP and Java, i imagine, i would split my project in different NPM modules. For example @mybigproject/customer, @mybigproject/cart and @mybigproject/checkout and so on.

But those submodules would be installed in the node_modules folder of the application skeleton. How would i tell for example Express, that the template files are in the different module directories? Or for example i use TypeORM for data access. So each module would have it's own set of models. How do those models know the database configuration data, as it's only in the main application skeleton, or the other way around, how does the application skeleton should know where to find the models?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you want to use node for a huge enterprise app?

Comment: Because it's amazingly fast, and it's very easy to include C++ code for time critical stuff. I was able to serve 5 million requests in 2.7 seconds, which was not possible with my previous Java environment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use npm modules for different parts of your project.

This components is integral part of your project and usually depend on your global config / schema / routing / etc

Just put it in different files and require it where you need it.

You can get an idea for folders structure from projects like [Sail.JS](https://sailsjs.com/)

Use npm modules if you writing some utility that going to serve you for different apps and you want an easy way to upgrade the utility code once for all your apps (or in case you want to share that utility as open source for all of us)

Answer (score 0):

NPM can install your local folder as a dependency. [(ref)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> - npm install <folder>:
>
> Install the package in the directory as a symlink in the current
>   project. Its dependencies will be installed before it's linked. If
>    sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies may be
>   hoisted to the toplevel node_modules as they would for other types of
>   dependencies.

Your module keeps its original location after installed and a symlink is created as the same name of your module folder in the top level `node_modules` folder.

In these custom sub-modules, you can use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) and relative paths to locate you configuration files to feed to database or other data consumers.

But remember that, sub-modules often serve as utility functions for the main module. They should be independent from the project context.